# apt-get not work and putty not connect

Tags: apt, libraries, shared-library

When I want to login to ssh by putty show me this errors:

```
Connection refused
```

and when I connect to Ubuntu via VNC when I login I see this errors:

```
apt-config: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
apt-config: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
apt-config: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
apt-config: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
/usr/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

and when I want to use `apt-get` command show me this error:

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

what can I do for fix it?
I can use every `apt-get` commands
error and error and error

Comment: Did you check your internet connection?

Comment: yes its good    i can connect via VNC but can not connect via putty

Answer (score 0):

Your system is missing zlib, a very common data compression library. I think that the package manager doesn't rely on it any more, so you should be able to run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlib1g
```

to fix the issue. There is a high chance your package dependencies are still messed up after that, so I recommend a sanitary

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to check for and (hopefully fix) any remaining package management issues.

Comment: thank you        but now how can in find MOUNTPOINT?   i mean any command for find it?

Comment: my moutpoint is :   /    so i when i type your commant say to me: cp: cannot stat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.* no such file or directory

Comment: I thought of a simpler approach, that should be working (see my edit). I'll revise it, if it turns out to not work.